# drupal jquery file not working

Tags: jquery, drupal

I am getting an error once I changed the $ to jquery in my js file. I understand that I shouldn't use the $ but why is jquery undefined? jquery comes standard in drupal right? I have noticed in firebug that the closing }); brackets for the ready function are being omitted..?

Comment: variables are case sensitive. Make sure it's jQuery and not jquery if you're actually using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, variables are case sensitive. Make sure that you've got it as `jQuery` and not `jquery` and everything should work :)